# Subdomain IP Address(Url) Masking via .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain, ip-address

I have a subdomain redirected to an IP address that currently works, but the IP address is visible in the address bar after redirection. 
My aim is to mask the IP address via .htaccess so only the subdomain address is visible.

This is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.gov\.ng$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.domain\.gov\.ng$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/197\.211\.55\.203\:8081" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You do the redirection yourself (last line) to an URL with an IP address ( which is a bad idea anyway), so why do you do that if you do not want it? Also you do not need all of this escaping in a `RewriteRule` target.

Comment: The idea is to mask the IP address so it doesn't show after the redirection. I'd like only the subdomain to be visible.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment: due to your last line **you** are doing the redirection to an IP  address yourself, so the question is why doing it if you do not like it? Did you try by removing that line?

Comment: I want the redirection. The aim is to have the redirection but without the IP Address in the address bar.

Comment: **YOU** put the IP in the URL see last line. I do not know  how much more obvious it can be, so I will stop trying to help, since you do not really try what it is suggested (again: did you try removing the last line?)

Comment: Tried without the last line and still got the same result.

Comment: Not possible, based on what you have shown (if you remove the last line, there is no redirection anymore whatsoever and even possibly a syntax error since RewriteCond alone is useless). So you will need to give more details for anyone to help you.